# c# regex - all white space before <pre>

Tags: c#, regex

Could you help me sort some regex.

I want all the whitespace before the `<pre>`

```
public Regex BeforePre = new Regex(@"^.*?(?=<pre>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

That will select everything before the `<pre>`, not just the whitespace. I want to only select the whitespace.

using http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
Pattern: ^.*?(?=<pre>)

Input: dewjdoiejw; test <pre>frfef</pre>
```

I believe it's `\s` but I can not get it to work.

Also I would like it so it works across multiple lines, for example:

```
Input: dewjdoiejw; test 

<pre>frfef</pre>
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

**UPDATE**

see.... http://goo.gl/8mX5c3

I want to remove all white space and tabs before `<pre>`

I only want to consider **all** text before `<pre>` and from that text remove all white-space/tabs.

**UPDATE**

from

```
<div>
    <div>
       some text

        <div>some text</div>     
    </div>

    <div>some text</div>   

</div>

<pre>
   <div>
      <div>some text

      <div>some text</div>
    </div>

   <div>some text</div>

   </div>
</pre>
```

to

```
<div><div>some text<div>some text</div></div><div>some text</div></div>
<pre>
   <div>
      <div>some text

      <div>some text</div>
    </div>

   <div>some text</div>

   </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: `\s*` works: `\s*(?=<pre>)`. Remove `^`, it matches the start of string.

Comment: @stribizhev  closer.... if i under stand this correctly its only getting white space between the last char and <pre> i.e. from test----><pre> and not the whole of  input.... I would like from the start to <pre>

Comment: I do not get what you are driving at. See the [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*(%3f%3d%3cpre%3e)&i=dewjdoiejw%3b+test+%3cpre%3efrfef%3c%2fpre%3e%0d%0a+%3cpre%3efrfef%3c%2fpre%3e%0d%0a+%3cpre%3efrfef%3c%2fpre%3e). You have not illustrated the expected output with an example, it is difficult to understand your requirement.

Comment: Maybe: [`^.*?(?=\s*<pre>)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%3f(%3f%3d%5cs*%3cpre%3e)&i=dewjdoiejw%3b+test+%3cpre%3efrfef%3c%2fpre%3e)

Comment: @stribizhev I can not figure out how to save a demo for you.... but basically in that put a couple of space between "dewjdoiejw;" and "test" and you will see that they are not picked up....hope that make sense.

Comment: The bottom of the page has tabs and the first one contains a permanent link. If this link is too long you can use [`goo.gl`](https://goo.gl/) to shorten it.

Comment: @Verarind sorry nope that's not it! i want only white space before <pre>

Comment: @Seabizkit: Why should I add spaces between "dewjdoiejw;" and "test" if you need whitespace only before `<pre>`? Do you understand that your requirement is impossible to meet?

Comment: Just a guess: use `@"(?s)^.*?(?=<pre>)"`. This is a poorly written regex, it still needs a fix.

Comment: @Seabizkit The reason behind this is very unclear. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to archive what you want to do. What's the reason for getting the whitespace between the input and the opening pre tag?

Comment: Okay you only want the whitespaces?: [`(?<![\s\r\n])[\s\r\n]*(?=<pre>)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5b%5cs%5cr%5cn%5d)%5b%5cs%5cr%5cn%5d*(%3f%3d%3cpre%3e)&i=dewjdoiejw%3b+test+%0d%0a%0d%0a+%3cpre%3efrfef%3c%2fpre%3e)

Comment: @Verarind thanks for the tips,  HI ALL see http://goo.gl/8mX5c3  I want to remove all tabs and spaces before <pre>

Comment: @Seabizkit I edited your question changing `<^pre>` to `<pre>`. Notice HTML tags are allowed when you use proper code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay: It's possible using only one regex:

[`(?s)([\s\r\n]*(?<value></?.*?>)[\s\r\n]*|(?<=</?.*?>)[\s\r\n]*(?<value>.*?)[\s\r\n]*(?=</?.*?>))(?=.*\n<pre>)`](http://goo.gl/bBOU3p)

Very short - I know :-)

[Code demo](http://ideone.com/ZWRX2Z)

Sorry - but don't ask me for explanation.

Comment: marked up! but... as its defo the closest....busy double checking, but what i find weird is the results of this in c# is skewed...

Comment: @Seabizkit Sorry I double checked it and can't find any differences to your sample. What exactly is the problem. Sorry the sentence _please double check_ won't help me. Say exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Seabizkit I hope you don't mean the spaces around the div tags in pre tag. My input looks a little different to your input. If you use the correct input you'll get the correct output.

Comment: @Seabizkit I changed the code sample one more time. Now I'm out. I took the input you gave, performed my regex, compared it to the expected output you also gave. The code sample shows both are equal! Sorry. My regex changes your input into your expected output. What's still wrong? Did you change the requirements? Sorry but I can't help you anymore.

Comment: dude **i** need to double check but till further i  am gona mark this as the answer as you have been a legend in effort.